# Custom Layout in Qt Designer

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, visual-c++, layout

Is there anyway that we can have Custom Layouts e.g. as defined at
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/examples-layouts.html

inside the Qt Designer ?

What would be the process to add such custom layouts in the Qt Designer? Can anyone guide about the steps involved for such custom enhancement in Qt Designer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create custom layout right inside QtDesigner. Instead you can write your layout as a plugin for QtDesigner. After this you can open QtDesigner and just drop your own layout to the form as any other widget in the Qt collection.

See [this quide](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/designer-customwidgetplugin.html) to find out how to write your own plugin for Qt. It's not so difficult.

Comment: but isn't plugins for Custom widgets ?

Comment: Don't undestand your question. Pleasy, clarify

Comment: I mean When we create plugins for QTDesigner isn't it for Creating Custom Widgets using QT Designer. I haven't seen a single example code in which a Custom Layout is being added to QTDesigner. My question is if it is possible then what procedure should i follow to have a custom layout available in QT Designer.

Comment: Adding custom layout is the same as adding custom widget. Plugins are not only for custom widgets (QWidget childs). You can inherits from QLayout, make your own layout and make the plugin as described in examples, even if your widget is not a _widget_ (not subclass of QWidget as clock in example)

Comment: But, will it be able to contain other widgets and give me preview like other default layouts does in the QT Designer ?

Comment: Hard to say. It should be. I just have no other ideas how to make it in a better way.

Comment: QLayout does not inherit from QWidget, so it CANNOT be done. See https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-3109 . The createWidget virtual method from QDesignerCustomWidgetInterface returns a QWidget pointer. So it's simply not possible to make it return a QLayout.

Comment: New link: [QTBUG-3109](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-3109).  But still no activity there... `:-(`